# Assuming Order of Execution of threads - Pitfall and Correction

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I came across the sample code.

**assuming_order_of_execution_pitfall.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 4

void* hello(void* arg)
{
   printf("Hello World from Thread%d\n", *(int*)arg);
   return NULL;
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t tid[N];
   int i;

   for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, hello, (void*)&i); //&i points to same address
   }

   for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Here, it mistakenly assumes that threads begin execution the moment they are created. The printf() statement may indeed be executed before the next call to pthread_create(), but the operating system is free to schedule the threads in any order. It is possible that all threads are created before any of them actually begin executing. Since all copies of `arg` point to the same address, which is changing in `main()`, the threads can print the same `identification number`.

I have tried to correct the above code by `using a unique address` to hold the identification number of each thread as given below

**assuming_order_of_execution_workaround.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 4

void* hello(void* arg)
{
   printf("Hello World from Thread%d\n", *(int*)arg);
   return NULL;
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t tid[N];
   int tno[N];
   int i;

   /* Added code */   
   for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      tno[i] = i + 1;
   }/* Added code */

   for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, hello, (void*)(tno+i)); // providing unique address for each thread
   }

   for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Is my correction the right method? Could some one suggest me a more correct method if there is one?

Comment: just a nit, but "tno+i" is much less clear than just indexing an array and using the address from that, such as "&tno[i]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this looks correct to me.